# How to remove "My settings" from user menu?

Tags: page-layout

Attempting to remove "My settings" from user menu, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that you're trying to simplify the UI for your users, but this isn't possible with standard functionality and you probably want users to be able to change their passwords etc. ;)

Comment: +1 "standard functionality"... so no JS hack to override the link? By the way, this is the my attempt to reach a "bare bones" config... :-) ...and the  "My Settings" page as a bunch of junk on it that I'm attempting to block/hide; meaning if the link is there, it appears like a pain, if not impossible to block the content/links on that page.

Comment: A similar side bar component hack might work, but again it'd definitely be a hack and could easily break with each release.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible for Classic view. Got to Set Up-> User Interface->Uncheck "Enable Improved Setup User Interface" under Advanced Section.